# Django existing cookie is not updating

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

What i am trying to do is updating the existing django cookie that already exist. I am creating a add to cart functionality but unable to add more items in existing cookie. Any help would be praise-able.
My code is:

```
def AddToCart(request):
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
    response = render(request,'index.html')
    if request.COOKIES.get('product'):
        request.COOKIES['product'] = {'name':product.name,'price':product.price,'img':product.image.url}
    else:
        response.set_cookie('product',{'name':product.name,'price':product.price,'img':product.image.url},
                        max_age= 14 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `request.COOKIES['product'] = ....` sets the product value only in the current request context ( or maybe a copy of the COOKIES dict, not sure really), so it won't set the cookie on the client side (response), and on the next request it will be overridden by the cookie it gets from the client response (which is the cookie prior to using `request.COOKIES['product'] = ....`).

So first you need to replace: `request.COOKIES['product'] = ...` by `response.set_cookie("product", ...)` for the value to change.

This will solve your cookie setting problem only, but not appending multiple products to your cookie.

For that i suggest you use `sessions` instead, as they are easier to use when it comes to manipulating data structures like dicts and arrays, for eg: on the client-side cookies approach, you need to write your own serialization to manipulate a dict/array stored in the cookie, example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2383482

Also you can refer to this answer to tell if you need cookie or db based sessions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18240232/4724196

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to use session for this situation. cheers. Upvoted.